# jQuery: something is wrong with how this loop is being done

Tags: jquery

```
function appendRefToLinks(ref){
    alert("hi");
        $j('a').each(function(i){
            alert('hello');
            $j(this).attr('href',$j(this).attr('href') + "?ref=" + $j.cookie.get("tb_ref"));
        }); 
}
```

I see the hi alert, but I have to links on my page, and I never see hello.... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably calling the function before the page is parsed.

You need to wrap the code that calls it in `$j(function() { ... });` so that it executes after the browser loads the page.

Answer (score 2):

Did all the links rendered before you call the function?

You should use [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead.

You can use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) so dynamic inserted links would also get the function.